# NGXS state change to often, performance issue in angular

Tags: angular, performance, redux, ngxs

I'm having performance issues in my NGXS logic, and i'm a little lost about how to fix it. So i will share my current code explain it and try to share the ideas to how to fix it.

So the code is

```js
import {Action, Selector, State, StateContext} from '@ngxs/store';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {produce} from 'immer';
import {finalize, from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {Attachment, ATTACHMENT_STATUS, ATTACHMENT_TYPE, ATTACHMENTS_STATUS, AttachmentVerification, Image} from '../attachment.model';
import {catchError, map, mergeMap, switchMap, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AttachmentDbService} from './attachment-db.service';
import {AttachmentValidationService} from '../attachment-validation.service';


export class ChargeAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentDb] Charge';
}

export class CountTotalAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Count total';

  constructor() {
  }
}


export class InitAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentDb] Init';
}

export class PageAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentDb] Next';

  constructor(public page: number, public limit: number) {
  }
}

export class ChangeTypeAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Type changed';

  constructor(public type: ATTACHMENT_TYPE) {
  }
}

export class ReloadAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Reload';

  constructor(public attachment: Attachment | Image) {
  }
}

export class VerifyStatusAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Verify all';

  constructor(public attachmentsById: ByLocalId<Attachment | Image>) {
  }

}

export class VerifyOneAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Verify one';

  constructor(public attachment: Attachment) {
  }

}


export class ChangeStatusAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Change status';

  constructor(public attachment: Attachment, public status: ATTACHMENT_STATUS) {
  }

}

export class VerifiedAttachmentsDb {
  static readonly type = '[AttachmentsDb] Verified';

  constructor(public payload: AttachmentVerification) {
  }

}

export function getLocalId(attachment: Attachment | Image): string {
  return btoa(`${attachment.id}${attachment.name}`);
}

export function addLocalId(attachment: Attachment | Image): void {

  attachment.localId = getLocalId(attachment);

  const childrenImages = (attachment as Image).children;

  if (!childrenImages || childrenImages.length < 1) {
    return;
  }

  childrenImages.forEach(child => child.localId = getLocalId(child));
}

export interface ByLocalId<T> {
  [localId: string]: T;
}

export interface ById<T> {
  [id: string]: T;
}

export class AttachmentDbModel {

  status: ATTACHMENTS_STATUS;

  total: number;
  page: number;
  limit: number;
  type: ATTACHMENT_TYPE;

  attachmentsById: ById<Attachment | Image>;
  verificationsByLocalId: ByLocalId<AttachmentVerification>;
}


@State<AttachmentDbModel>({
  name: 'attachments',
  defaults: {
    verificationsByLocalId: {},
    attachmentsById: {},
    status: ATTACHMENTS_STATUS.CHARGING,

    page: 0,
    limit: 25,
    total: 20,

    type: ATTACHMENT_TYPE.ALL
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class AttachmentDbState {

  constructor(private attachmentDbService: AttachmentDbService,
              private attachmentValidationService: AttachmentValidationService) {
  }

  @Selector()
  static attachments(state: AttachmentDbModel): ByLocalId<Attachment | Image> {
    return state.attachmentsById;
  }

  @Selector()
  static status(state: AttachmentDbModel): ATTACHMENTS_STATUS {
    return state.status;
  }

  @Selector()
  static verificationsByLocalId(state: AttachmentDbModel): ByLocalId<AttachmentVerification> {
    return state.verificationsByLocalId;
  }

  @Selector()
  static type(state: AttachmentDbModel): ATTACHMENT_TYPE {
    return state.type;
  }

  @Selector()
  static total(state: AttachmentDbModel): number {
    return state.total;
  }

  @Selector()
  static page(state: AttachmentDbModel): number {
    return state.page;
  }

  @Selector()
  static limit(state: AttachmentDbModel): number {
    return state.limit;
  }

  @Action(ChargeAttachmentsDb)
  chargeAttachments({setState, getState, dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>): Observable<any> {

    const {page, limit, type} = getState();

    return this.attachmentDbService.get(page, limit, type)
      .pipe(
        map((attachments: Attachment[] | Image[]) => {

          const attachmentsById = {};
          attachments.forEach(attachment => {
            addLocalId(attachment);
            return attachmentsById[attachment.id] = attachment;
          });

          return attachmentsById;
        }),
        tap((attachmentsById: ByLocalId<Attachment | Image>) => {
          setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
            state.attachmentsById = attachmentsById;
            state.verificationsByLocalId = {};
            return state;
          }));
        }),
        tap((attachmentsById: ByLocalId<Attachment | Image>) => {
          dispatch(new VerifyStatusAttachmentsDb(attachmentsById));
        }),
      );

  }

  @Action(CountTotalAttachmentsDb)
  countTotalAttachments({getState, setState}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>): Observable<any> {

    const {type} = getState();

    return this.attachmentDbService.count(type).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of(0);
      }),
      tap((total) => {

        setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
          state.total = total;
          return state;
        }));

      })
    );
  }


  @Action(InitAttachmentsDb)
  initAttachments({dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>): Observable<any> {

    dispatch(new CountTotalAttachmentsDb());

    return dispatch(new ChargeAttachmentsDb());
  }

  @Action(ReloadAttachmentsDb)
  reloadAttachment({dispatch, setState}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>, {attachment}: ReloadAttachmentsDb): Observable<any> {

    return this.attachmentDbService.reload(attachment).pipe(
      tap(attachmentLoaded => {
        setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
          addLocalId(attachmentLoaded);
          state.attachmentsById[attachmentLoaded.id] = attachmentLoaded;
          return state;
        }));
      }),
      tap(attachmentLoaded => {
        dispatch(new VerifyOneAttachmentsDb(attachmentLoaded));
      })
    );

  }

  @Action(ChangeTypeAttachmentsDb)
  changeTypeAttachments({dispatch, setState}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>, {type}: ChangeTypeAttachmentsDb): Observable<any> {

    setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
      state.type = type;
      return state;
    }));

    dispatch(new CountTotalAttachmentsDb());
    return dispatch(new ChargeAttachmentsDb());
  }

  @Action(PageAttachmentsDb)
  nexImages({setState, dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>, {page, limit}: PageAttachmentsDb): Observable<any> {

    setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
      state.status = ATTACHMENTS_STATUS.LOADING;
      state.page = page;
      state.limit = limit;
      return state;
    }));

    return dispatch(new ChargeAttachmentsDb());

  }

  @Action(VerifyStatusAttachmentsDb)
  verifyAttachments({dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>,
                    {attachmentsById}: VerifyStatusAttachmentsDb): Observable<any> {

    return from(Object.values(attachmentsById)).pipe(
      mergeMap((attachment: Attachment | Image) => {
        return dispatch(new VerifyOneAttachmentsDb(attachment));
      }, 2)
    );

  }

  @Action(VerifyOneAttachmentsDb)
  verifyOneAttachmentsDb({setState, getState, dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>,
                         {attachment}: VerifyOneAttachmentsDb): Observable<any> {

    dispatch(new ChangeStatusAttachmentsDb(attachment, ATTACHMENT_STATUS.ASKING));
    return this.attachmentValidationService.verifyUsage(attachment)
      .pipe(
        switchMap((verificationAttachment) => {
          dispatch(new VerifiedAttachmentsDb({attachment, result: verificationAttachment}));
          const childrenImages = (attachment as Image).children;

          if (!childrenImages || childrenImages.length < 1) {
            return of('');
          }

          return from(childrenImages)
            .pipe(
              mergeMap(childImage => {
                return this.attachmentValidationService.verifyUsage(childImage)
                  .pipe(
                    tap(verificationChildren => {
                      dispatch(new VerifiedAttachmentsDb({
                        parent: attachment,
                        attachment: childImage,
                        result: verificationChildren
                      }));
                    })
                  );
              })
            );
        }));

  }

  @Action(VerifiedAttachmentsDb)
  verifiedAttachment({setState, getState, dispatch}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>, {payload}: VerifiedAttachmentsDb): void {
    const status = this.attachmentValidationService.determinateStatusFromVerifications(payload.result);
    dispatch(new ChangeStatusAttachmentsDb(payload.attachment, status));

    setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {
      state.verificationsByLocalId[payload.attachment.localId] = payload;
      return state;
    }));
  }

  @Action(ChangeStatusAttachmentsDb)
  changeStatusAttachment({setState, getState}: StateContext<AttachmentDbModel>, {attachment, status}: ChangeStatusAttachmentsDb): void {

    const haveSameName = (a1: Attachment, a2: Attachment) => a1.name === a2.name;

    setState(produce((state: AttachmentDbModel) => {

      const attachmentInStore = state.attachmentsById[attachment.id];
      if (attachmentInStore) {
        const isChildren = !haveSameName(attachmentInStore, attachment);

        const attachmentToModify = isChildren ? (attachmentInStore as Image).children.find(c => haveSameName(c, attachment)) : attachmentInStore;

        if (isChildren && status === ATTACHMENT_STATUS.USED && attachmentInStore.status !== ATTACHMENT_STATUS.USED) {
          attachmentInStore.status = ATTACHMENT_STATUS.CHILDREN_USED;
        }

        attachmentToModify.status = status;
      }

      return state;
    }));

  }


}
```

The code help to found used file in one wordpress site, so i made one Angular/PHP plugin for this.

So the logic is:

- The code will find the total files count in the DB (initAttachments)
- Will ask for only one part of file and will be stocked in the store (i added one Map/Objet to found more easily when i have to update status)
- For each one of the file i will ask at WP if i can found the reference in the DB (code PHP not included)
- For each file asked i will change the status of the file in the Map/Object

BUT make all this consume to much, every time that i update the objet, angular will make one refresh in the front.

I thought two solutions:

- Have some "calculatingStatus" and hide everithing in the HTML page until this variable is stable
- Change the logic and make one big method and set at the end the result, this way angular will be executed only one time

There are others solutions?

You can see my front here:

```html
<h2>
  {{'attachment_db.title' | translate}}
</h2>
<p>
  {{'attachment_db.body' | translate}}
</p>

<div *ngIf="(isActivated$ | async) && ((isCrawled$ | async ) === false); else listResult">
  <h2>You activate the crawler option, please verify the crawler status to be CRAWLED, if not disabled the crawler option</h2>
</div>

<ng-template #listResult>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{'attachment.attachment_type' | translate}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select [value]="type$ | async" (selectionChange)="changeType($event.value)">

      <mat-option [value]="ATTACHMENT_TYPE.IMAGE">
        {{'attachment.image' | translate}}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="ATTACHMENT_TYPE.ALL">
        {{'attachment.all' | translate}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-paginator
    [pageIndex]="page$ | async"
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
    [pageSize]="limit$ | async"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 5, 10, 25]"
    [length]="total$ | async"
    (page)="changePage($event)"
  >
  </mat-paginator>

  <mat-card class="gris" *ngFor="let attachment of attachmentsArray$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <mat-card-title>
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          <span (click)="reload(attachment)">&#x21bb;</span> {{attachment.id}} - {{attachment.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <div>{{attachment.type}}</div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          {{attachment.status | translate}}
        </div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <div [ngSwitch]="deleteButtonOptionForParent(attachment) | async">
          <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.SHOW_DELETE">
            <button
              mat-raised-button
              color="primary"
              (click)="addToWantToParentDelete(attachment)">
              {{'attachment.add_delete_parent' | translate}}
            </button>
            <button
              mat-raised-button
              color="accent"
              (click)="addToIgnoredParent(attachment)">{{'attachment.add_ignore_parent' | translate}}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.CHILD_IGNORED">
            <p>{{'attachment.ignored_child_for_parent' | translate}}</p>
          </div>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.IGNORED">
            <p>{{'attachment.ignored_parent' | translate}} </p>
            <button
              mat-raised-button
              color="accent"
              (click)="removeFromIgnoredParentAttachment(attachment)">{{'attachment.undo_ignored_parent' | translate}}
            </button>
          </div>
          <p
            *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.ALREADY_TO_DELETE_CHILD">{{'attachment.child_in_delete_list_for_parent' | translate}} </p>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.ALREADY_TO_DELETE_PARENT">
            <p>{{'attachment.to_delete_parent' | translate}}</p>
            <button
              mat-raised-button
              color="accent"
              (click)="removeParentFromDeleteAttachment(attachment)">{{'attachment.undo_to_delete_parent' | translate}}
            </button>
          </div>

          <p
            *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.CHILD_DIFFERENT_NOTUSED">{{'attachment.child_different_used_for_parent' | translate}} </p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-content>
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td>{{'attachment.size' | translate}}</td>
          <td>{{attachment.size}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{'attachment.url' | translate}}</td>
          <td><a [href]="attachment.url" target="_blank"> {{attachment.url}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{'attachment.source' | translate}}</td>
          <td>{{attachment.src}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{'attachment.directory' | translate}}</td>
          <td>{{attachment.directory}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="attachment.sizeName">
          <td>{{'attachment.image_size_name' | translate}}</td>
          <td>{{attachment.sizeName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="attachment.height && attachment.width">
          <td>{{'attachment.dimension' | translate}}</td>
          <td>{{attachment.height}}x{{attachment.width}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{'attachment.checkers_result' | translate}}</td>
          <td>
            <umc-verification
              *ngIf="attachmentsVerificationsByAttachment(attachment) | async as verificationResult"
              [verificationResult]="verificationResult"
            >
            </umc-verification>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <section *ngIf="attachment.children?.length > 0">
        <mat-card *ngFor="let child of attachment.children; trackBy: trackByFn" class="gris-dark">
          <mat-card-title>
            <div class="container">
              <div>
                {{child.id}} - {{child.name}}
              </div>
              <div class="fill"></div>
              <div>{{child.type}}</div>
            </div>
          </mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>
            <div class="container">
              <div>
                {{child.status | translate}}
              </div>
              <div class="fill"></div>
              <div *ngIf="showButtonChildren$ | async"
                   [ngSwitch]="deleteButtonOptionForChild(child, attachment) | async">
                <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.SHOW_DELETE">
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="primary"
                    (click)="addToWantToChildDelete(child, attachment)">
                    {{'attachment.add_delete_child' | translate}}
                  </button>
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="accent"
                    (click)="addToIgnoredChild(child, attachment)">
                    {{'attachment.add_ignore_child' | translate}}
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.IGNORED">
                  <p>{{'attachment.ignored_child' | translate}}</p>
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="accent"
                    (click)="removeFromIgnoredChildAttachment(child, attachment)">
                    {{'attachment.undo_child_ignored' | translate}}
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.ALREADY_TO_DELETE_CHILD">
                  <p>{{'attachment.to_delete_child' | translate}}</p>
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="accent"
                    (click)="removeChildFromDeleteAttachment(child, attachment)">
                    {{'attachment.undo_to_delete_child' | translate}}
                  </button>
                </div>
                <p *ngSwitchCase="DELETE_BUTTON_OPTION.ALREADY_TO_DELETE_PARENT">
                  {{'attachment.parent_to_delete' | translate}}
                </p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </mat-card-subtitle>
          <mat-card-content>
            <table style="width: 100%">
              <tr>
                <td>{{'attachment.size' | translate}}</td>
                <td>{{child.size}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{'attachment.url' | translate}}</td>
                <td><a [href]="child.url" target="_blank"> {{child.url}}</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{'attachment.source' | translate}}</td>
                <td>{{child.src}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{'attachment.directory' | translate}}</td>
                <td>{{child.directory}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngIf="child.sizeName">
                <td>{{'attachment.image_size_name' | translate}}</td>
                <td>{{child.sizeName}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngIf="child.height && child.width">
                <td>{{'attachment.dimension' | translate}}</td>
                <td>{{child.height}}x{{child.width}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{'attachment.checkers_result' | translate}}</td>
                <td>
                  <umc-verification
                    *ngIf="attachmentsVerificationsByAttachment(child) | async as verificationResult"
                    [verificationResult]="verificationResult"
                  >
                  </umc-verification>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </mat-card-content>

        </mat-card>
      </section>

    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>

  <mat-paginator
    [pageIndex]="page$ | async"
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
    [pageSize]="limit$ | async"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 5, 10, 25]"
    [length]="total$ | async"
    (page)="changePage($event)"
  >
  </mat-paginator>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Are you using `OnPush` change detection? If not, I don't think the issue is due to NGXS but rather your template code with `ngIf` calling function on every change detection occurs. Specifically `attachmentsVerificationsByAttachment()`

Comment: @penleychan  Is a mix between my logic and the fact that ngxs is inmutable and i change a lots of value in the state, but i found a solution, i use to distinctuntilchanged function to reduce the execution of | asyn if nothing changed for the value wanted, this way i reduce a lots the changes and i made umc-verification use the direct observable, this reduce the charge from the global component


Because even if i used OnPush the result was the same. I think that ngxs should have some component state (they have one open "issue" in github to work in this feature from the last 2 or 3 years)